Minimum over a ball of a continuous function is continuous
I want to show that if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then the function
$$f_t(x)=\min_{\|x-y\|\leq t}f(y)$$
is continuous for any $t>0$. I am having a hard time since the minimum point can't really be traced, and its tricky since the ball itself is moving, so I have to consider which points are removed and which points aren't. Any hints?

It is defined in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

If this helps, after a rescaling you may assume $t=1$

Hint: $f$ is uniformly continuous on compact sets.

I'm still stuck... I am assuming I use uniform continuity on the union of the two balls $B_t(x)\cup B_t(x_0)$, but I am still stuck on how to proceed.

Let's say we move $x$ a little to get $x_0$. Then every point of ${y:|x_0-y|\leq t}$ can be obtained by moving some point from  ${y:|x-y|\leq t}$ by a little. But then that means that $f$ as well can change only a little for each such pair of points, and using the uniform continuity of $f$ we get that even over all such pairs the maximum change of $f$ is still little

Here is my proposed solution, please check (Here I used $F$ instead of $f$):
Let $\mathbf{x}_0\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Then since $F$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^d$, $F$ is uniformly continuous on $\overline{B_{2t}(\mathbf{x}_0)}$, so there is some $\delta_0>0$ such that for any $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}\in \overline{B_{2t}(\mathbf{x}_0)}$ with $\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|<\delta_0$, $\|F(\mathbf{x})-F(\mathbf{y})\|<\varepsilon$.
Now let $\delta=\frac{1}{2}\min(\delta_0, t)$ and $\mathbf{x}\in B_{\delta}(\mathbf{x}_0)$. Since $F$ is continuous, there exist minima of $F$ in both $\overline{B_t(\mathbf{x}_0)}$ and $\overline{B_t(\mathbf{x})}$, say $\mathbf{x}_0^{\star}$ and $\mathbf{x}^{\star}$. If both lie in the intersection of the balls, then $F_t(\mathbf{x})-F_t(\mathbf{x}_0)=0$ and we are done. Otherwise, suppose without loss of generality that $\mathbf{x}^{\star}\notin \overline{B_t(\mathbf{x}_0)}$. We first note that $\mathbf{x}^{\star}\in \overline{B_{t+\delta}(\mathbf{x}_0})\subset B_{2t}(\mathbf{x}_0)$, as
$$
  \|\mathbf{x}^{\star}-\mathbf{x}_0\|\leq \|\mathbf{x}^{\star}- 
 \mathbf{x}\|+\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0\|<t+\delta<2t.
$$
Then let $\mathbf{y}\in \overline{B_t(\mathbf{x}_0)}$ such that $\|\mathbf{x}^{\star}-\mathbf{y}\|<\delta_0$ since $t+\delta<t+\delta_0$. Then we have $|F(\mathbf{x}^{\star})-F(\mathbf{y})|<\varepsilon$ from uniform continuity, that is,
$$
  F(\mathbf{x}_0^{\star})-\varepsilon<F(\mathbf{y})-\varepsilon < 
  F(\mathbf{x}^{\star}).
$$
This shows $-\varepsilon< F(\mathbf{x}^{\star})-F(\mathbf{x}_0^{\star})$. Now, if $\mathbf{x}_0^{\star}\in \overline{B_t(\mathbf{x})}$, we are done as $F(\mathbf{x}^{\star})-F(\mathbf{x}_0^{\star})\leq 0$ by definition of $\mathbf{x}_0^{\star}$. Otherwise, we could repeat the same argument and reverse the roles of $\mathbf{x}_0^{\star}$ and $\mathbf{x}^{\star}$ to get $F(\mathbf{x}^{\star})-F(\mathbf{x}_0^{\star})<\varepsilon$. In any case, we have $|F_t(\mathbf{x})-F_t(\mathbf{x}_0)|<\varepsilon$.

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Let $t>0.$ Let $x_n\to x\in\mathbb{R}^n.$
First, I show that $\nexists\ \epsilon>0$ such that $f_t(x_n)> f_t(x)+\varepsilon$ for infinitely many $n.$ There exists a point $a$ in the closed ball $B(x;t),$ such that $f(a)=f_t(x).$ Let $a_n\in B(x_n;t)$ such that $a_n\to a.$ Since $f$ is continuous, $f(a_n)\to f(a)=f_t(x).$ But $f_t(x_n)\leq f(a_n)\ \forall\ n.$ The result follows.
Next, I show that $\nexists\ \epsilon>0$ such that $f_t(x_n)< f_t(x)-\varepsilon$ for infinitely many $n.$ Suppose by way of contradiction that such an $\epsilon>0$ does exist. Let $b_n\in B(x_n;t)$ such that $f(b_n)=f_t(x_n).$ There exists a strictly increasing subsequence $(m(n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $f_t\left(x_{m(n)}\right)< f_t(x)-\varepsilon$ for all $n.$ By Bolzano-Weiertrass theorem, there exists a subsequence $(k(n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $(m(n))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $b_{k(n)}$ converges to some $v\in B(x;t).$ Since $k(n)$ is a subsequence of $m(n),$ it follows that $f_t\left(x_{k(n)}\right)< f_t(x)-\varepsilon$ for all $n.$ But due to continuity of $f,$ the fact that $b_{k(n)}$ converges to $v$ implies $f\left(b_{k(n)}\right)$ converges to $f(v),$ which is impossible, since  $f\left(b_{k(n)}\right)=f_t\left(x_{k(n)}\right)< f_t(x)-\varepsilon, $ whilst $f(v) \geq f_t(x).$ This contradiction completes the proof.
I'm sure the second part can be proved directly i.e. without proof by contradiction.

Some thoughts.
We have
$f_t(x) = \min_{\|z\|\le 1} f(x + tz)$.
Let $z_0 := \underset{\|z\|\le 1}{\arg\,\min}\, f(x + tz)$.
Let $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$. We have
$$f_t(x + h) - f_t(x) \le f(x + h + tz_0) - f(x + tz_0), \tag{1}$$
and
$$f_t(x + h) - f_t(x) \ge \min_{\|z\|\le 1} [f(x + h + tz) - f(x + tz)].\tag{2}$$
(The proof is given at the end.)
$\phantom{2}$

Proof of (1).
We have
$$\min_{\|z\|\le 1} f(x + h + tz)
\le f(x + h + tz_0)$$
$$= [f(x + h + tz_0) - f(x + tz_0)] + f(x + tz_0)$$
$$= f(x + h + tz_0) - f(x + tz_0)
+ \min_{\|z\|\le 1} f(x + tz).$$
The desired result follows.
Proof of (2).
Let $z_1 := \underset{\|z\|\le 1}{\arg\,\min}\, f(x + h + tz)$. We have
$$f_t(x + h) = f(x + h + tz_1)
= [f(x + h + tz_1) - f(x + tz_1)] + f(x + tz_1)$$
$$\ge \min_{\|z\|\le 1} [f(x + h + tz) - f(x + tz)] + \min_{\|z\|\le 1} f(x + tz).$$
The desired result follows.
